# Set Transaction isolation level Play Framework 2.3

Tags: playframework-2.0

How can I set transaction isolation level in Play Framework 2.3? Currently it doesnt seem to be possible to set on the @play.db.jpa.Transaction annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set the isolation level](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsJDBC) directly on the BoneCP data source:

```
# Set a connection's default isolation level
db.default.isolation=READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: Thanks, will test out straight away!